# Unit testing LitElement events in firstUpdated

Tags: unit-testing, web-component, lit-element

I have a simple mixin:

```
export const mixin = superclass => class extends superclass {
  firstUpdated() {
    super.firstUpdated();
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('my-event', {
      bubbles: true,
      composed: true,
      detail: {
        myEventTriggered: true,
      },
    }));
  }
};
```

I want to test if `my-event` is fired. This is my test:

```
it('dispatches the custom event', async () => {
  const tag = class extends mixin(LitElement) {};
  const el = await fixture(`<${tag}></${tag}>`);
  setTimeout(() => el.firstUpdated());
  const { detail } = await oneEvent(el, 'my-event');
  expect(detail.myEventTriggered).to.be.true;
});
```

This works as expected but I'm not sure about the `setTimeout(() => el.firstUpdated());` line. Shouldn't `firstUpdated` be called after `await fixture`? I'm just following [open-wc's testing guide](https://open-wc.org/testing/testing-helpers.html#testing-events).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an answer from [@daKMor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3227915/dakmor):

> testing firstUpdated is a little tricky as as soon as you add it to the dom it's executed (with an arbitrary delay depending on the work your element is doing) https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle#firstupdated
>
> what you can do is:
>
> ```
> it('dispatches a custom event on firstUpdated', async () => {
>   const tag = class extends mixin(LitElement) {};
>   const el = fixtureSync(`<${tag}></${tag}>`);
>   const ev = await oneEvent(el, 'my-event');
>   expect(ev).to.exist;
> });
>
> it('dispatches a custom event on connectedCallback', async () => {
>   class Foo extends mixin(class {}) {};
>   const el = new Foo();
>   setTimeout(() => el.connectedCallback());
>   const ev = await oneEvent(el, 'my-event');
>   expect(ev).to.exist;
> });
> ```
>
> Note: this is untested code - if it works pls let me know and we could add that info and a little description to the [faq](https://open-wc.org/faq/). Maybe you could do a Pull Request?

For `connectedCallback`, since this callback is fired immediately after calling `fixture`, you can't catch it anymore. What you can do is define a new component and test its callback function in a `setTimeout`. An `HTMLElement` or `LitElement` is needed since `oneEvent` adds an Event Listener to the element.

```
it('dispatches a custom event on connectedCallback', () => {
  const tag = defineCE(class extends mixin(LitElement) {});
  const foo = document.createElement(`${tag}`);
  setTimeout(() => foo.connectedCallback());
  const ev = await oneEvent(foo, 'connected-callback');
  expect(ev).to.exist;
});
```